# How to replace certain substrings in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have my data set in a normal data model format:

```
var data = "Billing, alpha, beta"
```

But I want to modify this data by formatting the array by replacing "," with "/text/i"

```
var newData = [/Billing/i , /alpha/i, /beta/i]
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
var data   = "Billing, alpha, beta"
var y = x.split(',')
var newData  = y.replace(",", "/i,")
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: This might work if you remove `y` and just run the `replace` on `data`.

Comment: var newData = [/Billing/i , /alpha/i, /beta/i]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v2g1a72a/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the output contains space on from second string onwards

Comment: @SaurabhRaman Just `trim()` each item, see [update](https://jsfiddle.net/v2g1a72a/2/). Or [split with `,` and space](https://jsfiddle.net/v2g1a72a/4/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
var data   = "Billing, alpha, beta";
var y = data.split(',');
newData=[];
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++)
  newData.push(new RegExp( y[i].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,""),"i"));
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: he output contains space on from second string onwards

Comment: @SaurabhRaman Please accept my solution if you are satisfied

Comment: The output is an array of strings, while OP needs an array of RegExp objects.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge many thanks for your help....but there is little correction the output should also not contain ' " ' (double quotes)..... it should look like            ....  [/Billing/i,/alpha/i,/beta/i]

Comment: See my edit I've used Regex objects

Comment: I think this solves the problem, please upvote my answer